# Filling values by matching values in a second dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, match

I have two dataframes, data and glossary. data has four columns (Code1, Code2, Code3, Code4) that have values, some of which match glossary, and four blank columns (CodeA, CodeB, CodeC, CodeD).

Values are listed in glossary only once, but may appear multiple times in data.

```
data <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                   Code1 = c("team", "team", "crew", "group", "crew"),
                   Code2 = c("trust", "trust", "comms", "liking", "comms"),
                   Code3 = c("virtual", "virtual", "intact", "hybrid", "intact"),
                   Code4 = c("pooled", "pooled", "seqent", "recip", "sequent"),
                   CodeA = NA,
                   CodeB = NA,
                   CodeC = NA,
                   CodeD = NA)

glossary <- data.frame(CodeA = c("team", "crew", "group"),
                       CodeB = c("trust", "comms", "liking"),
                       CodeC = c("virtual", "intact", "adhoc"),
                       CodeD = c("pooled", "intensive", "recip"))
```

I would like to fill in CodeA-CodeD with values from glossary based on matching data$Code1 to glossary$CodeA. Glossary values are similar to Codes 1-4 in data but with some small changes. Code1 and CodeA will be the same but Codes 2-4 and Codes B-D will be somewhat different. So whereas Code3 in data has "hybrid" listed, for the new CodeC in data this will be listed as "adhoc" instead following the glossary.

The final result would look something like this:

```
data <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                   Code1 = c("team", "team", "crew", "group", "crew"),
                   Code2 = c("trust", "trust", "comms", "liking", "comms"),
                   Code3 = c("virtual", "virtual", "intact", "hybrid", "intact"),
                   Code4 = c("pooled", "pooled", "seqent", "recip", "sequent"),
                   CodeA = c("team", "team", "crew", "group", "crew"),
                   CodeB = c("trust", "trust", "comms", "liking", "comms"),
                   CodeC = c("virtual", "virtual", "intact", "adhoc", "intact"),
                   CodeD = c("pooled", "pooled", "intensive", "recip", "intensive"))
```

I've looked at some solutions using match and mutate in dplyr, though I haven't found anything that might elegantly let me fill in all four values in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `left_join`

```
data[1:5] %>%
   left_join(mutate(glossary, Code1 = CodeA), by = 'Code1')

  ID Code1  Code2   Code3   Code4 CodeA  CodeB   CodeC     CodeD
1  1  team  trust virtual  pooled  team  trust virtual    pooled
2  2  team  trust virtual  pooled  team  trust virtual    pooled
3  3  crew  comms  intact  seqent  crew  comms  intact intensive
4  4 group liking  hybrid   recip group liking   adhoc     recip
5  5  crew  comms  intact sequent  crew  comms  intact intensive
```

Comment: This is a great solution, thank you! I have used joins before but didn't think to use one here. Only issue is the join is creating additional rows, any idea what might be causing that?

Comment: Added unique(glossary) which seemed to fix the extra row issue. Thanks for the simple and elegant solution!